# Codeigniter Email class connect to smtp server from behind a proxy

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, proxy, smtp

I created a simple mailing list system for an application using the [Personalized Mailer](https://github.com/joeauty/Personalized-Mailer-CodeIgniter-Spark)  spark.

This spark uses codeigniter email class to connect to the smtp server and send mails.

The problem is that the server i'm working on uses a proxy to connect to internet so when i tested the mailing list it didn't work despite that it worked when i tested it on my local server.

Is there a way to modify the codeigniter email class to support connecting to smtp server using a proxy?

Comment: Are you getting an error or the emails are just not sending?

Comment: emails are just not sending because the server in connected to internet using a proxy so the code can't connect to the smtp server if it's not connected to the proxy server first.

Comment: Any more details on the proxy?

Comment: what kind of information do you need? i know that it is http proxy

Comment: after some debugging i got this error message: `Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command` despite that smtp settings are correct and tested on C# application

Answer (score 4):

Ok, to send the email your server have to make a tunnel through `fsockopen` and then use this tunnel to connect to SMTP. I can't specifically tell you what changes you have to made in codeigniter class but i do know a class which can send email via `HTTP PROXY`

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/14-PHP-Sends-e-mail-messages-via-SMTP-protocol.html

and following is a test script in which there is an option to configure the proxy.

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/31.html

In case if you are wondering how this is done and wan't to populate the same logic in codeigniter class, you probably have to first read through lines `884 - 953` of file `smtp.php`.

In my opinion, instead of mimicking the code of this class onto codeigniter mail class, you should use this class instead and change the Personalized Mailer code(which will be comparatively little effort) to use this class.

Comment: Does it support proxy authentication with username and password?

Comment: @M.B.Asfoor nope, it doesnot support natively the authentication but you can modify the `fsockopen` code to put basic HTTP authorization also (if your proxy server is designed to have BASIC HTTP AUTHORIZATION as per RFC 2617,e.g. in the form of https://username:password@www.example.com/path where example.com is your proxy) as depicted here: http://codeans.blogspot.com/2008/04/how-to-use-fsockopen-php-function-in.html .

Comment: I think it needs a lot of modification because it doesn't support html emails or attachments but i'll work with it for now.

Comment: @M.B.Asfoor No need for manual modification as you can use this class  http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9-PHP-PHP-mailer-to-compose-and-send-MIME-messages.html for html emails and attachment in conjuction with the above smtp class.

Comment: Ok i think i'll accept this as a solution for now, thank you for your help.